# How to use modified (calculated) value of a field in Drupal entity query condition?

Tags: 8

I have a link field for a content type. I am implementing a validation where users cannot enter a domain name in the field if it has been used already. For that purpose, I need a direct way to derive domain from the field value (full url) for comparison with the domain name of the url entered.

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type', 'ABC')
->condition('field_1', parse_url($url_entered)['host']->execute();
```

The problem is **field_1** is a full url where as I only want validation over the domain name.

Is it possible to do using Entity Query? If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To do so you can use **LIKE** operator in your query like the following:

```
$host = parse_url($url_entered)['host'];
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'ABC')
  ->condition('field_link', "%" . $host . "%", 'LIKE')->execute();
```

**UPDATE**
if you want to check that the exact host exist, you should select all values of your field and then compare with the entered host.

```
$host = parse_url($url_entered)['host'];
// Select all uris of field link.
$database = \Drupal::database();
$query = $database->select('node__field_link', 'nfl')
  ->condition('nfl.bundle', 'page')
  ->fields('nfl', ['field_link_uri']);
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$hosts = [];
// extract all hosts.
foreach ($result as $item){
  $hosts[] = parse_url($item)['host'];
}
// Check if the host already exist.
if (in_array($host, $hosts)){
  // Do what you want ici !
}
```

Comment: This does not work because we would end up blocking domains like 'Axyz.com', if 'xyz.com' has been entered. The solution I am looking for is a way to get the host from the field_link and then do the comparison.

Comment: check my update !

Comment: Thank you! This works.

Comment: You are so welcome, glad that helped, marked as the accepted answer if someone else needs it in the future